# How to perform "a.hover" with a certain .class?

Tags: html, css

What I want it to only perform -

```
a:hover {
background-color: #3b3b3b;
color: #d402d4;
}
```

with anything in a class.

I'll show an example excerpt of my code to help you better understand.

```
<a href="website2.html">
    <img alt="name" src="image.url" width=32" height="32">
    <br>
    <small>Name</small>
</a>
```

I only want -

```
a:hover {
background-color: #3b3b3b;
color: #d402d4;
}
```

to apply to `<small>Name</small>` but not `<img alt="name" src="image.url" width=32" height="32">`.
My idea was to add a class to `<small class="class1">Name</small>`, and only perform `a:hover {` on that class. I am not sure if this is possible or if there is a more simpler way?

Comment: PS: hover is a pseudo class, it's written as `:hover`, not `.hover`. (Change your question's title)

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' Sorry, I did right it like that in my code, I just missed it when writing this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
a:hover small {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    color: #d402d4;
}
```

or add a class in your `small` tag (recomended):

```
a:hover .your-small-class {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    color: #d402d4;
}
```

That way, when you hover the `a` tag, just the `.class` properties will change.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `a:hover small { ... }`, `a:hover .class1 { ... }` or something like this?

Comment: ```a:hover .class1 { ... }```

Comment: Well? Is it working?

Comment: ah yes, thank you!... I'm clearly new to this.

Comment: You're welcome :)